# Adding models to collection throws error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'idAttribute' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I'm having an error trying to add multiple models from the server to a collection. It throws the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'idAttribute' of undefined
```

Here is a test example which gives same error:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone.1.3.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var Mymodel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            id: null,
        },
        idAttributes: "id",
        render: function(){
            collection.add([{id:1, name: "name"},{id:2, name: "name"}])
        }
    });

    mymodel = new Mymodel();

    var mycollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: mymodel });

    collection = new mycollection();

    mymodel.render();

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`model` property](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model) of the collection class should be a model **constructor**, not an instance.

```
Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: Mymodel });
```

---

The model class has a [`idAttribute` property](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute), singular, which is already `'id'` by default.

---

Putting the `id` attribute in the `defaults` isn't necessary and could lead to problems down the road.

---

Other than the previous points, doing rendering within a model is bad practice. Use a [view](http://backbonejs.org/#View) for this.

```
render: function(){
    collection.add([{ id:1, name: "name" }, { id:2, name: "name" }])
}
```

I understand this is a test example, but if it wasn't, a model **class** shouldn't change a global collection instance. The whole point of classes is to scope the responsibilities to the class itself and nothing outside of it.

Using a global like that just goes against the whole point of using Backbone.

## Minimal code needed

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({}),
    MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: MyModel }),
    collection = new MyCollection();

collection.add([
    { id: 1, name: "name" },
    { id: 2, name: "name" }
]);
```

Comment: i know about the render, just wrote something to test.
could you please explain about the global? what do you mean?

Comment: i did this after your answer, but could you please explain about the global scope here?
can you give an example please?

Comment: @aleXela that's a whole concept that would go out of scope in this answer. But just as a quick note, a model **class** shouldn't change a global collection instance. But I understand that it's a test example, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: i understand you. and this is an example. 
thanks a lot. you helped me to settle things down.

Comment: one more thing, if I have two views, and one model. in such case can i give it like model: model to both? 
i have a lot of cases like this. what is a best practice for this?

Comment: @aleXela yes, passing a dependency down to a sub-view is the best practice. A Backbone model is made to be shared and views can easily use [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) to handle events from the data. I have listed on my profile lots of answers about Backbone that I wrote, take a look there, you'll probably find answers to questions you didn't even knew you had.